# PyTorch grid_sample for 2D tensors

Tags: python, pytorch, linear-interpolation

I have a 3D tensor `data` of shape `(N, W, D)` and another 1D tensor `index` of shape `(B,)`. I need to sample `data` using `index` such that my output should be of shape `(B,N,D)`. That is, for every element of `index`, I need to linearly interpolate `data` along dimension 1 and stack the resulting 2D tensors.

Is it possible to do this using PyTorch `grid_sample`? If yes, how?
The problems I'm facing are the following.

1. `grid_sample` interpolates in 2D or 3D, but not in 1D.
2. PyTorch requires batch size of `data` and `index` to be the same. But in my case, `data` does not have a batch dimension i.e., `data` is common for every element in `index`. I don't want to repeat `data`, `B` times unless there is no other way.

I could write a [bilinear interpolation code myself](https://github.com/NagabhushanSN95/Pose-Warping/blob/main/src/WarperPytorch.py#L212--293), but I don't want to handle all the boundary cases myself. `grid_sample` supports zero padding, which I want to use directly.

Comment: For your 2nd concern, you can extend `index` instead of repeating it.

Comment: Bilinear interpolation is already implemented in `torch.nn.functional.interpolate`

Comment: @DerekG `interpolate` simply upsamples the given `data` tensor. I don't want that. I want to sample `data` tensor at different locations given by `index` tensor.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail on "I need to linearly interpolate `data` along dimension 1 and stack the resulting 2D tensors". It's not clear from the question how the indexing value effects this interpolation.

Comment: I'd also note that using `expand` can be used to provide a tensor view of data with the same attributes as `repeat`,  i.e. data is not copied. This is likely a preferable approach if it lets you use `grid_sample` as you described.